# Serialize form not working in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Can you please take a look and help me realize where am I going wrong with this? Here is the jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/Hitman666/QcEkj/1/ but also here is that code

HTML:

```
<form action="#" id="gamesForm">
    <p>                                                        
        <input id="gName" type="text" class="medium" />
        <span class="notification information">Game name</span>
    </p>

    <p>                            
        <span class="notification information">Enabled:</span>
        <input id="gEnabled" type="checkbox" />              
    </p>

    <br />
    <!--Additional data for extra type-->
    <div id="extraAdditionalData" class="hidden">                            
        <p>
            <input id="rRacers" type="text" class="medium" />
            <span class="notification information">Racers</span>
        </p>

        <p>
            <input id="rVideoSet" type="text" class="medium" />
            <span class="notification information">Video set</span>
        </p>                                                         
     </div>                
</form>

<a href="#" id="saveConfiguration" class="graybuttonBig">Save everything!</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#saveConfiguration").click(function(){
        alert( $("form").serialize() );   
    });
});
```

All I'm getting is an empty string.

Answer (score 197, accepted):

You have to give your form elements `name`s!

This is independent of jQuery. Every form element must have a `name` to be considered for form submission as [*successful control*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#successful-controls):

> A successful control is "valid" for submission. Every successful control has its [control name](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#control-name) paired with its [current value](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#current-value) as part of the submitted [form data set](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#form-data-set). A successful control must be defined within a [`FORM`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#edef-FORM) element and must have a [control name](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#control-name).

jQuery just ignores those elements that don't have a name (or, depending on how it gets the elements, it might not even see them as the form itself has no reference to them).

Comment: I'm trying to use .serialize but with MVC 4 which already gave each control a name base on the model mapping, but i still have the serialized form = ""; 
what shall i do? :(

Comment: I had multiple forms on my page. Putting the specific id of the one I wanted to serialize made the difference for me. Something like `$("#gamesForm").serialize();` solved it for me.

Answer (score 47):

Something else that prevents `serializeArray()` from serializing properly is `disabled` inputs. `serializeArray` does not serialise disabled inputs, in much the same way that disabled inputs are not submitted with the form.

> A successful control is "valid" for submission.
>
> - Controls that are **disabled** cannot be successful.

[Source](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.12.1)

Answer (score 9):

Please add a `name` to your input field:

```
<input type='text' name='give_some_name' />
```

In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hitman666/QcEkj/1/) I have added a `name` and it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you're trying to select form like

```
$("form");
```

But this is equivalent to

```
getElementsByTagName("form");
```

This returns an array of objects.

So, instead you can use the **#id** selector, or use the index to access the form.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to give name attribute to all input controls like textboxes etc. Then please check whether your id's are clashing or not, I had the same id for form and the one section that's where my problem was.

Answer (score 0):

You have not referenced the form correctly in your javascript

Try changing to this:

```
$('#gamesForm').serialize();
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful not to put a form inside another form.

Obviously op has not but this could easily happen with modules and partials been placed incorrectly

Answer (score 0):

I must share my research, first of all, if you want to get all value from a form, please add:

```
<form method="post" name="MUST_ASSIGN" id="form">
...
```

`name="MUST_ASSIGN"` must be presented, and **DO NOT** duplicate form's ID.

Second: disable input can NOT be get. If you disable all input field before form.serialize(), you will get NOTHING.

This code is valid:

```
...
var Allinput = $('#form').serialize();
$(_self).find('input').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
...
```

But this code is get nothing:

```
$(_self).find('input').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
var Allinput = $('#form').serialize();
```

Good day!