# Add items to an array and then serialize() javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to add an item to an array in javascript and then serialize the array.  However, it doesn't seem to be working.

Please see below code, what am I doing wrong?

```
var currentParent = $(this).closest('tr');
var items = $("input,select", currentParent);
items["_token"] = $('input[name=_token]').val();
var strData = items.serialize();
```

Comment: `items` is not an array, it's a jQuery object. Just sticking properties on it, will probably not do what you think it will.

Comment: Perhaps https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.makeArray/

Answer (score 2):

Method `serialize` needs to be applied to a whole form, not to specific items in array, if you want to serialize existing object or array you need to use `param` instead

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/

As an example :

```
<form action="">
   <input class="token" name="token" value="someValue" />
   <input class="someData" name="someData" />
</form>

<script>
    alert($('form').serialize()) // should show you someData=&token=someValue
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4cxa36vp/

... or ...

```
var options = {
    token : $('input.token').val(),
    someData : null
}

alert($.param(options)) // should give you the same
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0ec8axot/

Also, make sure that your form fields have attribute `name`

[Serialize form not working in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6580450/serialize-form-not-working-in-jquery)

Comment: Thanks for your "... or ..." section Andy, I did spend some time trying to find out why I could not `.serialize()` a simple array. [jQuery `.serialize()` docs](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) do not even reference [`$.param()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) and for a moment I was going nuts.

Answer (score -1):

Try the below javscript code snippet. I have not tried but i think it might work:

```
var currentParent = $(this).closest('tr');
var items = $(currentParent).find("input, select");
items["_token"] = $('input[name=_token]').val();
var strData = items.serialize();
```

See the below fiddle link:
https://jsfiddle.net/nanncngr/

Comment: Thanks, I just tried this but if I do `alert(strData);` I can see that the _token is still not added to the array.

Comment: I think it should work. If the "_token" key is not formed, try the javascript push function to add the "_token" key.

Comment: I just tried `items.push([{_token:$('input[name=_token]').val()}]);` but still no luck

Comment: Your items is not an array, its actually an object. So, none of them will work.

Comment: So is there a solution?

Comment: I tried the above provided code. Its working for me.